# Can we mention our own idea of a project in the letter to a professor during grad applications?

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions, application

I am applying to 6 universities for MS and I have short-listed 2 professors from each university whose field of interest is nearly the same to that of mine.

Along with mentioning my interest in their work, can I also mention about a topic/project that I have been working on or 'am planning to work in future?

Please suggest!

PS: The topic/project will be similar to the research interests of the professor.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, that shows proactiveness, interest, creativity and many good things.

I'd suggest to publish it somewhere before, even if it's just a blog, arxiv.org, safecreative.org or your favorite option.

Otherwise it will be *their* idea, at least for some professors. Some of those may actually have had that idea (years) before you suggested it, so it may really be *their* idea. By publishing it you are able to prove that at least you got to the same idea/conclusion on your own, even if it was years after them. In case that matters to you.

Make sure to emphasize the research aspects of that project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try those services you mentioned. After publishing it, should I also give its link in the letter I write?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey The best part is that you can publish an "extended version" somewhere and add a summary with a link in the letter. This makes the letter less intimidating and provides additional information *iff* they want it.